# Including a C++ executable when freezing a Python script with PyInstaller

Tags: c++, executable, bioinformatics, biopython, blast

I've tried to read through the PyInstaller documentation and using spec files, as well as Google/SO, but haven't found any clear answers.

I have written a python script using Biopython, and have made it into an executable with PyInstaller and it works fine. However the script uses a Biopython function (NcbiBlastnCommandline()) that is a wrapper for the NCBI Blast+ blastn program (written in C++), and at the moment the user still needs to have the NCBI Blast+ installed locally.

Is it possible to package the C++ .exe along with the rest, so the end user only needs to download my executable and nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the part of the tutorial about [adding binary files](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-binary-files):

> To add binary files, make a list of tuples that describe the files needed. Assign the list of tuples to the `binaries=` argument of Analysis.

```
a = Analysis(...
     binaries=[ ( '/path/to/blastn.exe', 'blastn.exe' ) ],
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I previously tried this but only provided the path to the blast bin folder, and pyinstaller obviously failed to build an executable with that. Using this worked (altohugh the system seems to now be unable to find the blast file called by biopython in subprocess, but I guess that is a separate problem).